# How to append a python dictionary to json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have a section named **submissions** and in the section **users** with multiple commands each with the command and the description like this:

```json
{
    "submissions" : {
        "user1" : {
            "cmd1" : {
                "cmd" : "help",
                "des" : "Command to get help"
            }
        },
        "user2" : {
            "cmd1" : {
                "cmd" : "hello",
                "des" : "Greeting"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to append a new command to a user or a new user to the submissions like you can do with lists using Python?

For example you have this list:

```json
{
    "list" : [
        {
            "name" : "Tom",
            "age" : 34
        }
    ]
}
```

and you can add new people to this list with:

```py
...

person = {"name":"Kate","age":42}

data.append(person)
```

and kate appears on the list with the age.
But how can I define the new user so I can add this into the JSON file?

```json
"user3" : {
            "cmd1" : {
                "cmd" : "New command",
                "des" : "New description"
            }
        }
```

When I try to add something like **{"name":"Kate","age":34}**(to show the error) to **submissions** with the **.append()**, it throws this error:

```
data["submissions"].append(user)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can you add a new user to the JSON file with this formatting,
or is it better to store the user data like the list above?

Comment: You can't use `append()` with a `dict`. This is a question about updating a `dict` and nothing to do with `json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```py
user3 = {
            "cmd1" : {
                "cmd" : "New command",
                "des" : "New description"
            }
        }
```

then you just need to put this `dict` under the key `"user3"`:

```py
data["submissions"]["user3"] = user3
```